# "Too many redirects" - only LAN is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-302

Hello more experienced folks in here..

I am somewhat between newbie and rookie to MVC C# and I've built this webapp, which is basically a list with some create and edit pages to edit records in a SQL database.

I am using windows authentication through a domain controller and I am using AD groups to authenticate and login the user.

When I left the office yesterday my webapp was working as intended.

When I ran the project today from my home network (same computer and local webserver and database), I am having "Too many redirects" and I didn't really change anything and I did not redirect to the same page as I was trying to load.

I tried the usual tricks clearing browser cache and cookies and even connected to my companys VPN is giving me the same error.

The browser redirects to http://localhost:56810/Error/Index and the F12 console is giving me nada output...
No brakepoints I set are ever hit in the code..

This is my global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
var exception = Server.GetLastError();
Server.ClearError();
var httpException = exception as HttpException;

string action = "Index";

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 401:
                action = "NotAuthorized";
                break;
            case 402:
            case 403:
                action = "NotAuthorized";
                break;
            case 404:
                action = "NotFound";
                break;
        }

        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
    }

    // Avoid IIS7 getting involved
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Error/{0}", action));
}
```

This is my authorization tag in Web.config:

```
<authorization>  
  <allow roles="CompanyAD\Domain Users" />
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Without output I am clueless..

Where to start the debugging?
Where in the code does a HTTP request land first?

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes, Out commenting the authorization tag in the web.config solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Out commenting the authorization tag solved the problem.